# Create url from within HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a HtmlHelper extention that should create a set of links pointing to the current URL, but that have a different language code as their first parameter.
The languagecodes are passed in as a list.

Currently I require the UrlHelper to be passed in and do the following:

```
/*Warning: HACK*/
RouteValueDictionary vals = html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
vals["siteLanguage"] = "replaceMe";
string siteLanUrl = url.RouteUrl(vals).Replace("replaceMe", "{0}");
/*ENDHACK*/
```

Then I do a string replace so the "{0}" can be replaced with the set of language codes I have.

This is off course but ugly for a multitude of reasons. But I don't know how else I can generate these urls from with the HtmlHelper.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a helper for this...

```
public static string LanguageLink(this HtmlHelper html, string text, string languageCode)
{
    var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values);
    routeValues["languageCode"] = languageCode;

    string action = routeValues["action"].ToString();
    return html.ActionLink(text, action, routeValues);
}
```

.. then in your master page (or wherever)...

```
 <%= Html.LanguageLink("English", "en") %> 
 <%= Html.LanguageLink("Spanish", "es") %> 
 <%= Html.LanguageLink("German", "de") %> 
 <%= Html.LanguageLink("French", "fr") %>
```

These will link to the same controller/action & route values but will add the language code.  To get these to generate a friendly URL, you can add this *above the default route*.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     "languageRoute",                                       
     "{languageCode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",           
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" },
     new { languageCode = @"\w{2}" }
 );
```

(With this route, you wouldn't be able to match any controllers with a name of 2 characters, but that's probably fine).